# Encountered this error while trying to code a thread: Not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class, android-studio

I have this class called AnnouncementsActivity and I run a thread in its onCreate function this way:

```
 new GetAnnouncements().execute();
```

But, when I try to compile the code I get this error:

```
 Error:(42, 59) error: not an enclosing class: AnnouncementsActivity
```

Double clicking the error takes me to the doInBackground function of class GetAnnouncements:

```
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AnnouncementsActivity.this, announcementsList.get(1).get("baslik"), 5);
```

I execute the thread from AnnouncementsActivity, why does it say AnnouncementsActivity is not an enclosing class?

Answer (score 0):

An `enclosing` class is an `outer` class that contains an `inner` class. In other words both classes are defined in the same java file and the 'inner' one is defined inside the 'outer' one.

Whether you call/create it from another doesn't make it an enclosing clsas.

You don't show enough code to show what you are trying to do but `AnnouncementsActivity.this` looks very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are u change Toast inside to runonUIthread then solve ur problem.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     Toast.makeText(AnnouncementsActivity.this, announcementsList.get(1).get("baslik"), 5).show();
                }
            });
```

try after say response .